# Why isn't file downloading with Angular?

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I want to download files with Angular from a spring boot server, I made some functions like in this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n26StCRoeHA but I have no idea why they do not work for me.
This is the angular part

```
download() : Observable<HttpEvent<Blob>>{
  console.log("downloading");
  return this.http.get(this.url+'/crudops/read/attachment/'+this.attachmentId,{
    observe: 'events',
    responseType: 'blob'
  });
}

onDownloadFile(): void {
  this.download().subscribe(
    event => {
      console.log(event);
    },
    // (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    //   console.log(error);
    // }
  );
}
```

This is the spring boot part:

```
@GetMapping(path="/crudops/read/attachment/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Resource> readAttachment(@PathVariable("id") int id)
{
    System.out.println(id);
    Optional<Attachment> attachmentGot=attachmentRepository.findById(id);
    Attachment attachment=attachmentGot.get();
    var file=attachment.getFile();
    ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(file);
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .body(resource);
}
```

I verified if the functions are called when needed, they are, the requests are working but nothing gets downloaded. The onDownloadFile() function is called when clicking on a link.
[This is the request response:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3OJ7.png)
I tried with a txt file in postman and it returns the txt file corectly:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjSru.png)

Comment: Try this first
this.download().subscribe(data => console.log(data));

Comment: nothing happend after I added that

Answer (score 0):

```
<button (click)="downloadFile()">download</button>

downloadFile() {
    const fileUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/a.pdf'; // Replace with the actual file URL
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
      'responseType': 'blob'
    });

    this.http.get(fileUrl, { headers: headers, responseType: 'blob' }).subscribe(response => {
      const filename = this.getFilenameFromURL(fileUrl);
      this.download(response, filename);
    });
  }

  private getFilenameFromURL(url: string): string {
    const pathname = new URL(url).pathname;
    return pathname.substring(pathname.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
  }

  private download(blob: Blob, filename: string) {
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.target = '_blank'; // Open in a new tab/window
    link.download = filename;
    link.click();
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    link.remove();
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).